# Linked-Scroll Panel Feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to link two scroll-able `div` elements. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b75KZ/342/) fiddle example. The right side-panel shows all verbs that are present in the text on the left side.

The side-panel should always show at least all verbs that are **visible** in the left text. It represents some sort of text outline.
The following picture illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Text Outline]

While scrolling the whole page, the inner outline automatically scrolls too and always reflects the facts in the current visible text. I've seen similar behavior in [markdown-previews](https://youtu.be/IhLEHK4ZGAQ) before.

I'm not sure which scrolling behavior fit and feels nice. Maybe one could match the most upper verb in the side-panel always with the first visible verb in the text box.

I was able to synchronize the two elements while scrolling. However, the content of the side-panel does not match the view port of the text. Any help is appreciated. It's also okay for me to use any library.

**UPDATE:**

I thought about another alternative solution:

- Each verb in the left and right window receives an invisible marker
- Check which marker in the left window are visible in the view port
- Show same visible marker in the right window

Checking if a marker is visible should be easy. However, I'm not sure how to scroll the right window that all identified markers are visible in the right window too.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with scrolling only. The two boxes can't be the same height because you could have too many verbs in the text for them to fit in the right box.

Comment: Sure, assume that all current visible verbs in the left box fit in the current visible part of the right box. The provided fiddle is just a mock-up. I agree, that the height of the outline needs to be bigger as in this example. I also thought about a simpler approach than mentioned in the update. If one scrolls the left div say 20% of its height, the right div scrolls 20% of its height automatically.  This goes with the assumption that the two heights are rather proportional. Not sure about this. Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's [1] a working prototype that I've implemented a few weeks ago. The demo is using Waypoint to identify current visible elements in the viewport. I also manually adapted a few numbers in the Waypoint source code to have a better scrolling.

It's also possible to replace the Waypoint jQuery version with the framework-less one, in order to receive better performance.

```
<div id="overflow-scroll">
    <p>Our recent experience at this Jamaican themed restaurant in North Pinellas County Florida right off the Pinellas Trail
<span id="v1" class="continuous-group-left waypoint"><b>was</b></span>
   [...]
</div>
var continuousElements = document.getElementsByClassName('continuous-group-left')
  for (var i = 0; i < continuousElements.length; i++) {
      var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
        element: continuousElements[i],
        [...]
        exit: function(direction) {

        if(direction == 'down') {
            var topPos = document.getElementById('l_' + this.element.id).offsetTop;
            document.getElementById('div2').scrollTop = topPos+10;
      }
    },
    context: document.getElementById('overflow-scroll'),
    [...]
```

[1] https://jsfiddle.net/guw2otfk/11/